# How to access the property of an object that was created dynamically using __getattr__

Tags: python, python-2.7, attributes

I have some classes of resources:

```
class Tokens():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def create(self):
        return "Tokens resource"


class Users():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def create(self):
        return "Users resource"
```

I have a client class:

```
class Client():
    def __init__(self, account, password):
        self.account = account
        self.password = password

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        self.__dict__[attr] = globals()[str.capitalize(attr)]("a", "b")
```

Using this class I want to create an client object with lazy-loading attributes. Unfortunately, I get an exception first time. But the second time all is ok:

```
>>> client = Client("account", "password")
>>> print client.tokens.create()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'create'
>>> print client.tokens.create()
Tokens resource
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is not the [Lazy Loading Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading)

Comment: return the value of the attribute??

Comment: I don't get it. How do you have access to "client.tokens"? Where are tokens initialized?

Comment: `__getattr__` *assigns* the new attribute, but doesn't *return* it; it's only on the subsequent call (which is dealt with by `__getattribute__` instead) that the attribute actually makes it back to the caller.

Comment: Thanks for the right answers in the comments :)

Comment: @JamesMills I probably incorrectly expressed. I mean the creation of object attributes when accessing this property for the first time when I was writing "lazy-loading attributes".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are never *returning* the created attribute:

```
def __getattr__(self, attr):
    self.__dict__[attr] = globals()[str.capitalize(attr)]("a", "b")
    return self.__dict__[attr]
```

You do set the attribute in `self.__dict__`, so the next attempt to access it finds the attribute and never calls `__getattr__` again.

I'm not sure why you are using `str.capitalize()` as an unobund method when you can just call it on `attr` directly:

```
def __getattr__(self, attr):
    self.__dict__[attr] = globals()[attr.capitalize()]("a", "b")
    return self.__dict__[attr]
```